# Can't install ubuntu phone - click package missing

Tags: 12.04, installation, phone

I tried installing Ubuntu phone from my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit but I am unable to install phablet-tools because of a dependency on the package click which I can't figure out where it's supposed to come from. I am following the official guide at ubuntu.com/phone/install, I've added the repo but I am unable to install:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  phablet-tools : Depends: click but it is not installable
  Recommends: ubuntu-dev-tools but it is not going to be installed`
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas on where I can get the click package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install click
```

Best Regards
Miguel